# Is it possible to constrain a generic type to be a subset of keyof in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

In the current version (2.1) of TypeScript I can constrain a method argument on a generic class to be a property of the generic type.

```
class Foo<TEntity extends {[key:string]:any}> {
    public bar<K extends keyof TEntity>(key:K, value:TEntity[K]) { }
}
```

Is it possible in the current type system to constrain the key part even further to be a subset where the value of the key is of a certain type?

What I'm looking for is something along the lines of this psuedo code.

```
class Foo<TEntity extends {[key:string]:any}> {
    public updateText<K extends keyof TEntity where TEntity[K] extends string>(key:K, value:any) {
        this.model[key] = this.convertToText(value);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

For clarification I added a more complete example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
type object = { [key: string]: any };

class Form<T extends object> {
    private values: Partial<T> = {} as T;

    protected convert<K extends keyof T>(key: K, input: any, converter: (value: any) => T[K])
    {
        this.values[key] = converter(input);
    }

    protected convertText<K extends keyof T>(key: K, input: any)
    {
        this.values[key] = this.convert(key, input, this.stringConverter);
    }

    private stringConverter(value: any): string
    {
        return String(value);
    }
}
```

[Demo on typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20object%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Form%3CT%20extends%20object%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20values%3A%20Partial%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20convert%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(key%3A%20K%2C%20input%3A%20any%2C%20converter%3A%20(value%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20T%5BK%5D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.values%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20converter(input)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20convertText%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(key%3A%20K%2C%20input%3A%20any)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.values%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20this.convert(key%2C%20input%2C%20this.stringConverter)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20stringConverter(value%3A%20any)%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20String(value)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

`convertText` will give an error saying that `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'`.

Given

```
interface Foo {
    s: string
    n: number
}
```

The compiler can tell that this will work

```
this.convert('s', 123, v => String(v));
```

and this will not

```
this.convert('n', 123, v => String(v));
```

I'm hoping I can constrain the `convertText` method to keys where the value is of type `string` to get type safety on the key parameter.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're asking. Are you referring to the value in the `TEntity` map? Or the key? Can you edit your question and give example of how you would use it?

Comment: The psuedo code is the example on how I would use it. It will give an error that `this.model[key]` cannot be assigned a string since `TEntity[K]`is not declared to be a string.

Comment: No, there's no way of doing that. The compiler has no way of knowing whether `TEntity[K]` is a string or not, you defined the values to be `any`, so how can the compiler know?

Answer (score 8):

It is possible (using a non-class example here). The following will ensure that `T[P]` is a string.

```
function convertText<T extends {[key in P]: string }, P extends keyof T>(data: T, field: P & keyof T) {
    // ...
}
```

The idea is to narrow the type of `T` to only the fields inferred in `P` and set the exact type you want, in this case `string`.

Test:

```
let obj = { foo: 'lorem', bar: 2 };
convertText(obj, 'foo');
convertText(obj, 'bar'); // fails with: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Comment: Worked great on Classes as well but wasn't able to get it working on interfaces. Kudoz

Comment: That looks like a very circular set of constraints.  I'm surprised it can be resolved. 
 How could we make a similar constraint using keyof this? I.e. where func(field: keyof this) and this[field] is of type ClassA?

Comment: I have no idea why, but it does work on the invoker side. But now, inside `convertText` function, how to make compiler to know that obj['foo']="some value" is perfectly valid? Right now I have compilation error saying that `TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[P & keyof T]'.`

Comment: @altschuler maybe you could take look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67642380/how-to-declare-indexer-type-of-function-argument-type-that-tk-is-of-type-x-so