# How to declare indexer type of function argument type that T[K] is of type X so t[k]=x will be a valid expression

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define function that will modify boolean property of an object when object and property name is given. I have found something that almost does what I want in here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42615501/1527544

and from the caller side it works fine, but function body still yelds errors. How to handle that without suppressing it with ts-ignore?

[Live example TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIZgCYBsCmAxLVAcwB4AVRHADyh0wGdEBvAbQGscBPRGJABQC6ALkQAjOHFzpEAXwA0iPpRp0MjDpzjBEZAHwAKDKiioRZBcBg4sGEUoBkiDVp0BKZgChEiL4iMmWS2sMAUQAXkRgVCx6HABuRAB6RM5gxhwAJwy4DJ1OAAccRABycUkcdGKeRjA4KERUenoYIjBUUVxEKDgugqLishYHJy4XMgFigDp9ACYAZhmZ119klDgAdy6e3HqIOABbfJhcXLZazag0ev9UQKsbUJhGVGgQaKxuFyg%20sQkpJHQGEQ9GQcBANjERXeGxwGAA-B4ZB4PMkIO9MsCYBgiuscmxGJYwDgPGhMLgCMR9ExgIQiEIoBkQDg5G19jghMVgBJivIAEQ04i81wJZLdExYD6IPZZHDQRAAWkQtUoWRyJMB5NpVIFdIZTJZqDZHK5cB5cl5rJwQpFiSIMAAbjh0qqMgpmpAipbqkq6g1fuVpIrHRluNjmhlYZC0Pb4BlkUA)

```
function handleFlag<T extends {[key in P]: boolean }, P extends keyof T>(data: T, field: P & keyof T) {
  
  data[field] = false; //yelds error Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'T[P & keyof T]'.(2322)
  // how to let compiler know that data[field] is actually of type boolean and should be allowed?
}

//caller side works fine
handleFlag({flag:true,name:'foo'},"flag"); //totally correct - no error
handleFlag({flag:true,name:'foo'},"name"); //gives error, since name is not a boolean - very desired behavior
```

in my other question [How to declare argument type as key of given object in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67640872/how-to-declare-argument-type-as-key-of-given-object-in-typescript) i am suggested to read [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/91nl42/typing_key_into_object_with_specific_lookup_type/) but I have no idea what is happening there....

Comment: Why are you using `T` at all instead of just `{[K in P]: boolean}` for `data`? Is there something that `T` is giving you?

Comment: I don't actually know. Iv copied that from the SO answer mentioned above https://stackoverflow.com/a/42615501/1527544

Comment: I think this is one of those places where TypeScript is a minefield. There's a haphazard mixture of too-strict typing that stops you from doing safe things, alongside too-lax typing that allows you to do unsafe things. If you just want to get this to compile without throwing [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) at the problem, you could do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMy6zm) where you widen `data` to its constraint, at which point the (possibly unsafe) assignment is allowed. Should I write up an answer?

Comment: @jcalz so in this case, we can say that it is almost as good as using ts-ignore. Difference is that I wont be able toassign anything else than boolean (which is good) but still to possibly non boolean property. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant way, but you can cast it to help the compiler:

```
(data as {[key in P]: boolean })[field] = false;
```

Note that this is a valid up-cast, so all type checks still work.

Comment: Why is this cast needet in the first place? `data` is already extending that structure. Its kind of like having `<T extends X>` and still have to do `(t as x).access`

Comment: With just `T extends X`, you can't guarantee that _any_ T property complies with X.
I think that when you make the call to your method, the compiler is kind of instantiating the conditions with a concrete type, and make the proper validation. But once inside the method there's no concrete type, so the compiler ends up assuming that `data`can have properties that aren't boolean.

Comment: That would explain why method call is correctly validated and only boolean property names are accepted but body still needs some tweaks.